# Trim CString after GetDlgItem()

Tags: c++, mfc, trim, c-strings

Hopefully someone can help me with this issue!

I have a dialog with a few Combo Boxes that are populated with data, which the user is supposed to fill in and then click save. When you click save, the program creates an outfile with the chosen data in it.

My problem is that I need to trim everything at the hyphen before saving the file!

The Combo Boxes is populated with strings that looks something like this:

- 4010-First
- 4020-Second

And I want it to look like this after the trim:

- 4010
- 4020

And:

- PH-Peter Hansen
- JK-John King

And I want it to look like this after the trim:

- PH
- JK

I use Visual Studio 6.0 and MFC.

Here is the `OnOK` Code:

```
void CExportChoices::OnOK() 
{

CString sFileName, name, height, weight, age, haircolor, eyecolor, initials, group;


CWnd* pWnd = GetDlgItem(IDC_NAME);
pWnd->GetWindowText(name);

sFileName.Format(".\\Export\\%s_export%d.txt", name, GetTickCount());
ofstream outfile(sFileName,ios::out);


pWnd = GetDlgItem(IDC_HEIGHT);
pWnd->GetWindowText(height);

pWnd = GetDlgItem(IDC_WEIGHT);
pWnd->GetWindowText(weight);

pWnd = GetDlgItem(IDC_AGE);
pWnd->GetWindowText(age);

pWnd = GetDlgItem(IDC_HAIRCOLOR);
pWnd->GetWindowText(haircolor);

pWnd = GetDlgItem(IDC_EYECOLOR);
pWnd->GetWindowText(eyecolor);

pWnd = GetDlgItem(IDC_INITIALS);
pWnd->GetWindowText(initials);

pWnd = GetDlgItem(IDC_GROUP);
pWnd->GetWindowText(group);


outfile << "Height="        <<      height      <<      "\n";
outfile << "\n";
outfile << "Weight="        <<      weight      <<      "\n";
outfile << "\n";
outfile << "Age="           <<      age         <<      "\n";
outfile << "\n"; 
outfile << "Hair color="    <<      haircolor   <<      "\n";
outfile << "\n";
outfile << "Eye color="     <<      eyecolor    <<      "\n";
outfile << "\n";
outfile << "Initials="      <<      initials    <<      "\n";
outfile << "\n";
outfile << "Group="         <<      group       <<      "\n";

outfile.close();

CDialog::EndDialog(22);

}
```

Thanks in advance!

**------------------------------------UPDATE-------------------------------------**

Okay, after some confusion I have finally found a solution that works somewhat for me..

Here is what I was trying to do after the advice you guys gave me:

Data from the ComboBox:

**"4010-group"**

My code:

```
pWnd = GetDlgItem(IDC_GROUP);
pWnd->GetWindowText(group);

int i = group.Find("-");

if (i >= 0)
{
group = group.Mid(0, i);

}

MessageBox(group); // results = 4010-group
```

It did not work.

I thought maybe there was some UNICODE related issue, so I changed the data in the ComboBox from **"4010-group"** to **"4010 group"** and tried this:

```
pWnd = GetDlgItem(IDC_GROUP);
pWnd->GetWindowText(group);

int i = group.Find(" ");

if (i >= 0)
{
group = group.Mid(0, i);

}

MessageBox(group); // results = 4010
```

It works! But I don't understand why the hyphen doesn't work, does anyone have a clue?

Comment: The term you're looking for is not trimming, it *substring*.

Comment: Why don't you use the CString::TrimRight Method ??

Comment: Oh okay! I'll take a look at substring then! 

I tried:

group.TrimRight('-');

but it does not work for me

Comment: I'm not sure. TrimRight has always worked for me. Can you show me how you used it here?

Comment: Please don't use `CDialog::EndDialog()`. Instead use the default `CDialog::OnOK()` implementation to close the dialog. Please also use MFC-standard Data Exchange mechanism to replace ugly calls like `GetDlgItem()`

Comment: Ok thanks for the tips Andrew! I will take a look at it and try to change it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CString::Find` and `CString::Mid`, which is similar to `wstring::find` and `wstring::substr`

See also [CString functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa252634%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

```
CString s = L"4010-First";

int i = s.Find('-');
if (i >= 0)
{
    s = s.Mid(0, i);
    TRACE(L"%s\n", s); //output: "4010"
}
```

or to get first and second part:

```
CString s1 = s.Mid(0, i);
CString s2 = s.Mid(i + 1);
TRACE(L"(%s)(%s)\n", s1, s2); //output: (4010)(First)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a solution to your problem that requires less code.  Using the little used and somewhat misunderstood CString method [SpanExcluding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300649(v=vs.60).aspx), you can accomplish your task in less lines.

```
CString str = L"PH-Peter Hansen";
CString newStr = str.SpanExcluding(L"-");
```

Will result in returning only “PH”.

Answer (score 2):

Re: "I don't understand why the hyphen doesn't work, does anyone have a clue?"

There are many symbols that look like a hyphen but are not: [dash, en-dash, em-dash, etc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash) You need to figure out which one was used as a delimiter in your source.